# Qual è il significato di "stigmate antonomastiche" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> La verità è che Lisa è sempre stata ed è tuttora una genovese purosangue; ne ha le **stigmate antonomastiche**, una discrezione che rasenta la bruschezza dei modi, un controllo della parola e dei sentimenti che sono agli antipodi dell'espansività partenopea.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "stigmate antonomastiche" in questa frase. Malgrado aver letto le definizioni di ["stigmate"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stimmate/) e ["antonomastico"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/antonomastico/) nel vocabolario Treccani, non riesco a capire il senso di questa espressione. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direi che con un giro di parole ricercato intenda che quella Lisa avesse tutte le caratteristiche (uso figurato di 2.a nella definizione Treccani di “stigmata”) che si attribuirebbero classicamente ai genovesi, è cioè una genovese per antonomasia (vedi, nella definizione di “[antonomasia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/antonomasia/)”, il “riferimento a persona, o a cosa, a cui si riconosca o si attribuisca una qualità, una dote, una condizione in misura eccellente e perciò distintiva”).

Evidentemente per Gassman il genovese tipico è chiuso e riservato (una certa vulgata umoristica lo vorrebbe anche tirchio).